# How to read a specific key-value pair from Lua-returned table in C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I am writing a Lua script which will return a table like this:

```
return_table = {
  "service"="ISH"
  "worker"="Tim"
  "place"="Seattle"
  "abbrevation"="ITS"}
```

After returning the table, I have another C++ code which needs elements returned from Lua. Now the problem is that, I want my C++ code to read a specific key-value pair from the table, which means that I want this to be realized in C++:

```
city = return_table["place"]
```

Would this be possible? I know that in C++ Lua API, once a "return" is called, the lua script will stop, so I cannot do multiple return from Lua to C++ wherever I need a returned value. Now what I can do is to return a table full of the elements that I will need, but reading them in C++ is of random order.....

Comment: I don't know Lua, but in C++ you can store that data in `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: You will need `lua_getglobal()` to put `return_table` on the Lua stack, then `lua_getfield()` to get the value for a specified string key from the table, and then `lua_tostring()` to get a character pointer for the value to C++. All those functions are explained in the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/).

Comment: @siffiejoe thank you very much for your comments. It works